# How to override the hash function for tuple in reduce rdd for spark 2.4.3?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data that look like this

```
((key_1, key_2), value1)
```

Is there a way to reduce the `rdd` base on both keys?

I am seeing the default reduce doesn't map the exact key

ie.

```
val a = (key_1a, key_2a)
val b = (key_1b, key_2b)
```

where `key_1a` , `key_2a` , `key_1b` and `key_2b` are all unique

but I see both `a` and `b` being map to the same reduce context, so I am guessing the default hashing is not what I want, is there a way to override it?

```
myRdd.reduce((agg: ((String, String), Array[Byte]), agg2: ((String, String), Array[Byte])) => {
    // I am seeing the key being map in one reduce context is different
    println(agg._1)
    println(agg2._1)

    agg2
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` aggregates the entire `RDD`. You need `myRdd.reduceByKey`.